# Getting "this class is not key value coding-compliant" when trying to perform NSPredicate in Swift 4

Tags: swift, nspredicate

Whenever I try and use an NSPredicate it errors out saying:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Project.Object 0x7fc805c23770> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key happyfacevalue.'

Now I can't figure out why it refuses to work. I even tried initializing the array I want with @objc and it still crashes.

I understand that the filter feature works incredibly easy, but I need to be able to use NSCompoundPredicate. I don't think I can achieve the level of detailed searching with the Filter feature, that I can with an NSCompoundPredicate.

```
    let tempPredStr = model.selectionQueryArray[count + 1] + "==" + model.inputQueryArray[count + 1]

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: tempPredStr, NSNumber(value: false))
    arrayOfPredicates.append(predicate)

    /*
    let predicateIsNumber = NSPredicate(format: "isStringOrNumber == %@", NSNumber(value: false))
    let predicateIsEnabled = NSPredicate(format: "isEnabled == %@", NSNumber(value: true))
     */
    count = count + 1
}

let andPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, subpredicates: arrayOfPredicates)

let filteredArray = (predicateArray as NSArray).filtered(using: andPredicate)
```

I want it to just predicate using the pre-built predicates and to produce an array of objects.

Comment: Why use all of this Objective-C baggage in your Swift code? Use a Swift Array and use `filter` instead of an NSPredicate. It's much easier and you get proper compile-time type checking.

Comment: I think `filter` in Swift can be as detailed or as complex as you need. You get to write the code it uses to do the filtering.

Comment: I have been using filter, but I need to make super complex filters, based off of a bunch of selectable variables. I am not sure how to build complex filters without using static code.